# Creating fake model in djanago rest framework without migrating it for using in swagger

Tags: django, swagger

I am trying to implement swagger ui using in Django Rest Framework using drf-spectacular. I don't have any database insatlled yet and in this phase I don't want to implement or create any database or table. I only want to create an API Contract with different Endpoints and showing required and response data types in swagger ui.

My question is, that how can I create a model (fake model) without implementing it and without migration?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a serializer and implement all required fields there. If you need different serializers for request and response just pass them in swagger_auto_schema decorator. Use request_body parameter for request one and responses for response. Here's an example:

```
class MyRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.Charfield(max_length=128)
    last_name = serializers.Charfield(max_length=128, allow_blank=True)

class MyResponseSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    my_custom_response_field = serializers.IntegerField()

class MyAPIView(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=MyRequestSerializer(), responses={200: MyResponseSerializer()})
    def get(self, request, format=None):
         request_data = MyRequestSerializer(request.data)
         do_smth
         response_serializer = MyResponseSerializer(request_data)
         return Response(response_serializer.data)
```